# Laravel Ajax Update on several select

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, axios

I'm working on a shopping cart with Laravel.

I have :

Routes :

```
Route::post('/panier/ajouter', 'CartController@store')->name('cart.store');
Route::patch('/panier/{product}', 'CartController@update')->name('cart.update');
```

View :

```
 <table class="table" id="table-shoppingcart">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-center" id="item-title-shoppingcart"></th>
                        <th class="text-center" id="size-title-shoppingcart">Taille</th>
                        <th class="text-center" id="quantity-title-shoppingcart">Quantité</th>
                        <th class="text-center" id="price-title-shoppingcart">Prix</th>
                        {{-- <th class="text-center" id="delete-title-shoppingcart"></th> --}}
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (Cart::content() as $product)
                    <tr>

                        <th><img class="text-center item-content-shoppingcart" src="{{ $product->model->image }}"></th>
                        <td class="text-center td-table-shoppingcart size-content-shoppingcart">S</td>
                        <td class="td-table-shoppingcart quantity-content-shoppingcart">
                            <select name="quantity" class="custom-select text-center quantity" id="quantity" data-id="{{ $product->rowId }}">
                                @for ($i = 0; $i < 5 + 1 ; $i++)
                                <option {{ $product->qty == $i ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $i }}</option>
                            @endfor
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center td-table-shoppingcart price-content-shoppingcart">{{ getPrice($product->subtotal()) }}</td>

                    </tr>
            @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Ajax

```
$('body').on('change','#quantity',function(){
    var quantityvalue = this.value;
    var classname = document.querySelectorAll('#quantity')
    Array.from(classname).forEach(function(element) {
        console.log(element);
        var id = element.getAttribute('data-id')
        axios.post(`/panier/${id}`, {
            quantity: quantityvalue,
            _method: 'patch'

        })
        .then(function (response) {
           // console.log(response);
           console.log("refresh");
            $("#refresh").load(location.href + " #refresh");
            $("#refresh2").load(location.href + " #refresh2");
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log("erreur");
           // console.log(error);
        });
    })
});
```

Controller

```
public function update(Request $request, $rowId)
    {
        $data = $request->json()->all();

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'quantity' => 'required|numeric|between:0,5'
        ]);

        Log::info($data);
        if($validator->fails()) {
            Session::flash('error', 'La quantité du produit ne doit pas dépasser 5.');
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Cart Quantity Has Not Been Updated']);
        }
        if( $data['quantity'] == 0){
            Cart::remove($rowId);
        }
        else {
            Cart::update($rowId, $data['quantity']);
        }
        Session::flash('danger', 'La quantité du produit est passée à ' . $data['quantity'] . '.');
        return response()->json(['success' => 'Cart Quantity Has Been Updated']);
    }
```

The problem is when I have several different products in my basket like this :
[image]

For example, if I want to change the quantity of my product 1, it will also change the quantity of my product 2 with the same value.

How can I dissociate the update from each selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a result of foreach loop you get multiple selects with `id="quantity"`, which is not valid html. Remove ids and handle changes by class

```
$(document).on('change', '.quantity', function(){
    let id = $(this).attr('data-id') // $(this) is an instance of the current select changed
    let quantityvalue = $(this).val()
    axios.post(`/panier/${id}`, {
        quantity: quantityvalue,
        _method: 'patch'

    })
    ...
})
```